# DAX totals not including all values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am building a shared dataset in Power BI used for sales analysis. Our sales are either external (To customers) or internal (Between stores)

The business would like all measures to reflect external sales only, unless one actively filters on or uses TransactionType (internal/external) in a report.

I can set up a measure to do this just fine

```
Invoiced Amount = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_sales_invoice_line[InvoicedAmount]), 
    'dim_transaction_type'[TransactionTypeCode] = SELECTEDVALUE(dim_transaction_type[TransactionTypeCode], "Eksternal")
)
```

the only issue I have is that when using this measure with transaction code, it does not produce the desired total

[image]

What am I missing in my DAX code that will allow me to have it total the entire dataset when using transaction code in either filter or report?

Comment: If you want to total the entire dataset, you should just use fact_sales_invoice_line[InvoicedAmount] column in the table. Because all measures reflect external sales only, the total value is a sum of only external sales.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead-

```
Invoiced Amount = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_sales_invoice_line[InvoicedAmount]), 
    FILTER(
        ALL(fact_sales_invoice_line),
        'dim_transaction_type'[TransactionTypeCode] = SELECTEDVALUE(dim_transaction_type[TransactionTypeCode], "Eksternal")
    )    
)
```

Comment: Same result unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this code to see the total result: It will ignore filter on the [TransactionTypeCode].

```
Invoiced Amount =
CALCULATE (
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( fact_sales_invoice_line[InvoicedAmount] ),
        ALL ( dim_transaction_type[TransactionTypeCode] )
    ),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( dim_transaction_type[TransactionTypeCode], "Eksternal" )
)
```